# Why I don't have ASSETS folder after running npm install - laravel 5.7?

Tags: node.js, laravel, compiler-errors

First of all, sorry if the question is basic, I'm a newbie into Laravel and code in general.

I've run several times the

```
npm install
```

later on following tutorials the

```
npm run dev
&
npm run prod
```

And I do understand the compile process, but I just see that in every video and post around there, there is a folder called `Assets` created in `Resources` and It's not being created in my situation.

[My folders in PHP Storm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s8ar.png)

Just let me know if it's normal, or I'm experiencing some issue. Maybe I'm just watching outdated posts where the `assets` folder creation wasn't deprecated yet, or not.

Thank you all and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `assets` folder is removed from Laravel 5.7.. You are in the latest version. So It's okay.

[image]

Source: [Laravel 5.7 Resources Directory Changes](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-resources-directory-changes)

Comment: just wondering now, as I'm following a tutorial, where should I simply drop the files given (it's a css, fonds and js folder) that were meant to be added in the assets folder. Will dropping them in the "resources" folder work?

Comment: how are you going to add a link to html now using this folder structure?ex `<script src="{{ asset('resources/js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>` what is correct `src` now?